# clase Scanner problemas

Tags: java

```
  Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numerosIngresados;
        int numeroMayor = 0;
        int numeroDiez = 0;
        int sumaImpares = 0;
        int contadorImpares = 0;
        int contadorNumeros = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("Digite 6 numeros");
            numerosIngresados = lector.nextInt();

            if(numerosIngresados == 0){
                break;
            }else if(numerosIngresados > numeroMayor){
                numeroMayor = numerosIngresados;
            }else if(numerosIngresados == 10){
                numeroDiez++;

            }else if(numerosIngresados % 2 == 1){



            }
             numerosIngresados = contadorNumeros++;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero mayor es " + numeroMayor);
        System.out.println("El numero diez ha sido ingresado " + numeroDiez + " veces");
        System.out.println("La cantidad de numeros ingresados han sido: " + contadorNumeros);
        //System.out.println("El promedio de la suma de los numeros impares es " + sumaImpares);
```

al imprimir las veces que he puesto el numero 10 me dice que lo he introducido una vez menos de lo que en realidad lo he hecho. y como puedo hacer para calcular el promedio de los numeros impares que he introducido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente, no te imprime de manera correcta la cantidad de veces que introduces el número 10 por que lo estas metiendo en un `else if` donde deacuerdo a tu flujo ese bloque de condiciones jamás se llega a ejecutar(al menos no del modo esperado)
debería bastar con que cambies el `else if()` simplemente por un `if` de este modo indistinto de los demás bloques condicionales siempre verificará si se introducen números 10 y ejecutara el contador que le declaraste

Entonces tu código debería quedar de este modo

```
import java.util.*;
class Lector
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numerosIngresados;
        int numeroMayor = 0;
        int numeroDiez = 0;
        int sumaImpares = 0;
        int contadorImpares = 0;
        int contadorNumeros = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("Digite 6 numeros");
            numerosIngresados = lector.nextInt();

            if(numerosIngresados == 0){
                break;
            }else if(numerosIngresados > numeroMayor){
                numeroMayor = numerosIngresados;
            } if(numerosIngresados == 10){
                numeroDiez++;

            }else if(numerosIngresados % 2 == 1){

            }
             numerosIngresados = contadorNumeros++;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero mayor es " + numeroMayor);
        System.out.println("El numero diez ha sido ingresado " + numeroDiez + " veces");
        System.out.println("La cantidad de numeros ingresados han sido: " + contadorNumeros);
        //System.out.println("El promedio de la suma de los numeros impares es " + sumaImpares);
    }
}
```

**MUESTRA DEL CÓDIGO FUNCIONANDO**

```
C:\Users\Alfred\Desktop\>javac Lector.java

C:\Users\Alfred\Desktop\>java Lector
Digite 6 numeros
10
Digite 6 numeros
10
Digite 6 numeros
5
Digite 6 numeros
8
Digite 6 numeros
7
Digite 6 numeros
4
El numero mayor es 10
El numero diez ha sido ingresado 2 veces
La cantidad de numeros ingresados han sido: 6
```

Comment: Hola que tal??. muchas gracias por su respuesta. en cuanto a lo otro de sacar el promedio de los numeros impares que introduzca. por donde iria el desarrollo de eso??.saludos

Comment: Hola, ya lo pude resolver. Gracias igual. Saludos